# setting axes limits and animation in plotlyjs.jl Julia

Tags: plotly, julia, plots.jl

I want to set coordinate axes limits in the plotlyjs.jl. The code is as follows:

```
plot(scattergl(x = MatPointCoords[:,1,40], y = MatPointCoords[:,2,40], mode="markers") )
```

I cannot find any thing in the julia documentation related to this. Any help is appreciated.

Also, I want to animate the plot for last index in MatPointCoords. How can I do it? Julia plots documentation is not being very helpful in this too.

Comment: I have no experience with Julia, but I guessed that it is the same as the axis limitation in python, so I took a look at the [official reference](https://plotly.com/julia/axes/#setting-the-range-of-axes-manually). I think it is possible to limit the axes with this content. There are no samples in the animation, so I don't think that feature is available at this time. If there is, it would be in the manual.

Comment: Why do you bother to answer, if you cannot answer the question????

Comment: I use python plotly a lot, so I just thought I'd comment on it to give you a hint. I don't know that it takes experience to make a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axes limits are set in layout:

```
plot(scattergl(x = MatPointCoords[:,1,40], y = MatPointCoords[:,2,40], 
               mode="markers"),
     Layout(xaxis_range=[a, b], yaxis_range=[c,d])
```

For animation see this example:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/plotlyjs-jl-animation/70058/3